# Are these 3-parameter LogNormal Distributions the same/correct?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

**Source 1:** https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html

Which from what I calculate, it should be:
[image: Source 1]

**Source 2:** https://lmfit-py.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.12/builtin_models.html#lognormalmodel
[image: Source 2]

**Source 3:** Springer Chapter (https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-017-1431-0_7)

[image: Source 3]

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "No."  And you should probably mention any restrictions on the parameters (such as being greater than zero).

Source 2 does not give a pdf as it does not integrate to 1 for all values of the parameters (even after restricting $A>0$ and $\sigma>0$.  (It simply represents a shape to use in a regression as opposed to something related to samples from a probability distribution.)

Sources 1 and 3 are equivalent formulations of a shifted lognormal distribution if $a=loc$, $b=\log (scale)$, and $c=\sigma$.